# SQL DB2 On clause associated with join operator or in a Merge statement is not valid

Tags: sql, db2, left-join

So I'm trying to run a query and find it producing an error I'm not clear on:

```
    select a.employer_id, a.customer_id, s.service, count(a.account_num) as "TOTAL_COUNT" 
        from dhs01.msa_account  a
left outer join dhs01.alt_services s
    on a.customer_id = s.customer_id
        and s.service = 'TH'
        and a.employer_id not in (select s2.employer_id from dhs01.alt_services s2 where s2.service = 'TE')   -<<<<----- THIS IS THE BAD LINE
where 
        a.ACCT_MAINT_FEE = 'E'
        AND a.STAT = 'O'
        AND a.OPEN_CONFIRM_DATE < (CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS) ---first of the current 

    group by a.employer_id, a.customer_id, s.service;
```

The query is very close to working, but for some reason the subselect query is throwing an error (if I remove that, I get results that are largely correct, except for not excluding those results I want to exclude).  I've generally seen subselects in on clauses work in db2, and actually have examples which appear similar where it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from dhs01.msa_account  a
left join table
(
select s.*
from dhs01.alt_services s 
where s.customer_id = a.customer_id and s.service = 'TH'
and not exists
(
select 1
from dhs01.alt_services s2 
where s2.service = 'TE' and s2.employer_id = a.employer_id
)
) s on 1=1
```

instead of:

```
from dhs01.msa_account  a
left outer join dhs01.alt_services s
    on a.customer_id = s.customer_id
        and s.service = 'TH'
        and a.employer_id not in (select s2.employer_id from dhs01.alt_services s2 where s2.service = 'TE')   -<<<<----- THIS IS THE BAD LINE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems absolutely correct, but still you may use below query -

```
SELECT          a.employer_id, 
                a.customer_id, 
                s.service, 
                COUNT(a.account_num) AS "TOTAL_COUNT" 
FROM            dhs01.msa_account a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dhs01.alt_services s 
ON              a.customer_id = s.customer_id 
AND             s.service = 'TH' 
WHERE           a.acct_maint_fee = 'E' 
AND             a.stat = 'O' 
AND             a.open_confirm_date < (CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS) --first of the current 
AND NOT EXISTS  (SELECT NULL
                 FROM   dhs01.alt_services s2 
                 WHERE  s2.service = 'TE'
                 AND    a.employer_id = s2.employer_id)
GROUP BY        a.employer_id, 
                a.customer_id, 
                s.service;
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can try below query if you want to filter in `On Clause`:

```
select a.employer_id, a.customer_id, s.service, count(a.account_num) as "TOTAL_COUNT" 
    from dhs01.msa_account  a
left outer join dhs01.alt_services s
on a.customer_id = s.customer_id
    and s.service = 'TH'
    and a.employer_id <> (select distinct s2.employer_id from dhs01.alt_services s2 where s2.service = 'TE' and a.employer_id=s2.employer_id)   
where 
    a.ACCT_MAINT_FEE = 'E'
    AND a.STAT = 'O'
    AND a.OPEN_CONFIRM_DATE < (CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS) ---first of the current 

group by a.employer_id, a.customer_id, s.service;
```

### If you want to exclude all employer_id which have `service = 'TE'` in result in less execution time then you should try below query:-

```
select a.employer_id, a.customer_id, s.service, count(a.account_num) as "TOTAL_COUNT" 
    from dhs01.msa_account  a
left outer join dhs01.alt_services s
on a.customer_id = s.customer_id
    and s.service = 'TH'   
where 
    a.ACCT_MAINT_FEE = 'E'
    AND a.STAT = 'O'
    AND a.OPEN_CONFIRM_DATE < (CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS) ---first of the current 
AND not exists(select 1 from dhs01.alt_services s2 where s2.service = 'TE' and a.employer_id=s2.employer_id)

group by a.employer_id, a.customer_id, s.service;
```